# case statement query based on date

Tags: sql-server

I posted this query earlier. Posting it again with more details to help better understand my problem

Original Dataset

```
Name          currency  lcfeerate   effectivestartdate
Institution1    USD      0.0029      7/9/2009
Institution1    CAD      0.0029      7/9/2009
Institution1    USD      0.0034      4/3/2017
Institution2    CAD      0.0029      7/9/2009
Institution2    USD      0.0029      7/9/2009
Institution3    CAD      0.0029      7/9/2009
Institution3    USD      0.0029      7/9/2009
Institution3    USD      0.0034      4/3/2017
Institution3    CAD      0.0034      4/3/2017
```

I need to run query such as to return one row each corresponding to each institution and corresponding currency. i.e. Institution1 will have 2 rows, 1 each for USD and CAD. Similarly Institutions 2 and 3 will have 2 rows each. Hence the final result is a table of 6 rows.
The rule to filter the table is that for each institution and currency, lcfeerate is chosen based on the effectivestartdate.
When the effectivestartdate lies between declared startdate and enddate then the feerate is chosen for that effectivestartdate. When there is no effectivestartdate between the declared startdate and enddate then it checks for the previous maximum effectivestartdate.
Here are two examples of the output required.
Example 1

```
Start date- 1/1/2017        
End date-   3/31/2017       
Name         currency   lcfeerate   effectivestartdate
Institution1    USD      0.0029        7/9/2009
Institution1    CAD      0.0029        7/9/2009
Institution2    CAD      0.0029        7/9/2009
Institution2    USD      0.0029        7/9/2009
Institution3    CAD      0.0029        7/9/2009
Institution3    USD      0.0029        7/9/2009
```

Since there are no effective startdates between declared start date and end date, it chooses the next available effective startdate of 7/9/2009 and provides lcfeerate corresponding to those dates for each institution and currencies USD and CAD.

Example 2

```
Start date- 4/1/2017        
End date-   5/31/2017       
Name         currency   lcfeerate   effectivestartdate
Institution1    CAD       0.0029      7/9/2009
Institution1    USD       0.0034      4/3/2017
Institution2    CAD       0.0029      7/9/2009
Institution2    USD       0.0029      7/9/2009
Institution3    USD       0.0034      4/3/2017
Institution3    CAD       0.0034      4/3/2017
```

In this case, since for Institution 3 effectivestartdate of 4/3/2017 lies between declared startdate and enddate it provides new lcfeerates for it. For institution1, USD rate has effectivestartdate between the declared dates so that one is provided and rest 3 rows do not have effectivestartdate between the declared dates hence the previouse effectivestartdates are chosen to provide lcfeerate.

It is very easy to sequence the table as per the effectivestartdate and group by name and currency to get the highest value but the condition I have I am not sure how to write this query.

The query I have tried is here:

```
declare @startdate as datetime = '1-Jan-2017';
declare @enddate as datetime = '31-Mar-2017';

select bankname, lcfeerate
        ,case when effectivestartdate between @startdate and @enddate then lcfeerate 
           when effectivestartdate not between @startdate and @enddate
        then (select *
        from (
              select *, row_number()
              over (partition by name, currency order by effectivestartdate desc) as seqnum
                from table1
             ) t1
        where seqnum = 1)end as lcfeerate
     from table1
```

I get the following error:

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the
>   subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

Comment: Format code pls. It's so hard to read.

Comment: Well the problem is this `then (select *`. You can only return one value because it's going into one column. Maybe you need to move the part into outer apply and select it into several columns?

Answer (score 0):

You are pretty close, but you got the ranking wrong. First ranking criterion should be whether the date is in the date range, second is the date in descending order.

```
select name, currency, lcfeerate, effectivestartdate
from
(
  select 
    name, currency, lcfeerate, effectivestartdate, 
    row_number() over (partition by name, currency order by
          case when effectivestartdate between @startdate and @enddate the 1 else 2 end,
          effectivestartdate desc) as rn
  from table1
) ranked;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @startdate as datetime = '1-Jan-2017';
declare @enddate as datetime = '31-Mar-2017';

select bankname, lcfeerate
        ,case when effectivestartdate between @startdate and @enddate then lcfeerate 
           when effectivestartdate not between @startdate and @enddate
        then (select top 1 lcfeerate
        from (
              select lcfeerate, row_number()
              over (partition by name, currency order by effectivestartdate desc) as seqnum
                from table1
             ) t1
        where seqnum = 1)end as lcfeerate
     from table1
```

I hope it is helpful for you.